# Form automatically renders create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

My index page loads fine. I have this in the view:

```
<%= form_tag('tickets') do %>
  <%= select_tag 'Filter', options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, 'id', 'full_name'), include_blank: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Filter', class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the controller:

```
def index
  tickets = Ticket.all
  @tickets_by_date = tickets.group_by(&:start_date)
  @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
end

def create
  @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
  if @ticket.save
    redirect_to tickets_path
  else
    render 'tickets/new'
  end
end

def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:name, :summary, :creator_id, :start_date, :end_date, :customer_id, :status_id, :priority_id, :type_id, :assignee_id)
end
```

When I click on the submit of the filter form on the index field, I get this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in TicketsController#create

param is missing or the value is empty: ticket
```

This is the html that is getting rendered on the index page:

```
<form action="tickets" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="4RUirKnLeJrEVFLfICuHmiNWr7gkUw9ehHPExsOXS8lYlmRl4bFIstHosRFIedtQie2pLxrOVG1ZBM+ksNQvqA==">
  <select name="Filter" id="Filter" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Cameron Aziz</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

Why is it calling the create controller? How do I fix it so that it basically re-renders the `#index` action page?

Comment: I think it's because your form is sending a `post` request, assuming you used `resources :tickets` a `GET` to `tickets_path` will go to `index`, while a `POST` to `tickets_path` will go to `create` Change it to `<%= form_tag('tickets', method: 'get') do %>`

Comment: worked, although the url is `http://localhost:3000/tickets?utf8=✓&Filter=1&commit=Filter` how do we get rid of that `utf8` and `commit` items?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment after sending it. Change your form tag to `<%= form_tag('tickets', method: 'get') do %>` The default form action is `POST` which is why it uses that path.

Comment: same... worked, although the url after submitting is `http://localhost:3000/tickets?utf8=✓&Filter=1&commit=Filter` how do we get rid of that `utf8` and `commit` items?

Comment: Those are automatically added by using `<%= form_tag(etc..) %>` The easiest way to not have them would be to just make an HTML form.

Comment: Forgot to add, `commit=Filter` is from the button, don't set a name on the button and it won't pass a value.